# Angular 2 is taking 7 seconds to load (large project)

Tags: javascript, performance, angular

I am creating a very large system using the angular 2. I am splitting into small modules and using "lazy load" to load them.

But while loading the first module, which has about 300 typescript and HTML files, including: Components, Models, Enum, Services, Templates. The trend is the system grow more.

According to Chrome, the problem is in the interpretation of JavaScript, oh wonder: What is the recommended size of a module so that it is not slow? How many file at most should have a module?

Note: The problem is not in the download files, but in its interpretation/execution.

```
angular: 2.0.0
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 6.4.0
os: win32 x64
browser: chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you've already compiled the TS to straight JS and aren't using in-browser transpiling?

Comment: I'm using the BUILD own Angular2